# How to prevent original site url from being shown on links I create

Tags: jquery, html

I managed to get data stored in different variables and then manually create a link with data coming from those variables.

My site link you can [see here](http://wordpressdev.burnnotice.co.za/)

First I select an option from the first dropdwon, then I choose the dates, click on the black button, and afterwards, by click on the "Nothing here", the site should generate a url from a different website.

Example: www.lekkeslaap.co.za/akkommodasie-in/Saab?q=Saab&start=11+4+2017&end=17+4+2017&pax=2

But it is happening that before that url, it is also giving me the main site url so the link is looking like this which is wrong:
http://wordpressdev.burnnotice.co.za/www.lekkeslaap.co.za/akkommodasie-in/Saab?q=Saab&start=25+4+2017&end=30+4+2017&pax=3

How can I prevent the main site url(my site) from coming before the link I want to redirect?

I initially did everything [in a pen here](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/gmyoWM?editors=1111)

Here my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var txtFromDate, txtToDate;
  $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      txtFromDate = selected;
      var dt = new Date(selected);
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
      $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
    }
  });
  $("#txtTo").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      txtToDate = selected;
      var dt = new Date(selected);
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
      $("#txtFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
    }
  });

  $('.submit-here').click(function() {
    // var link = day_1+month_1+year;
    var date1 = $("#txtFrom").datepicker('getDate'),
        day_1  = date1.getDate(),  
        month_1 = date1.getMonth() + 1,              
        year_1 =  date1.getFullYear();

    var date2 = $("#txtTo").datepicker('getDate'),
        day_2  = date2.getDate(),  
        month_2 = date2.getMonth() + 1,              
        year_2 =  date2.getFullYear(); 

    var where = $('#selection :selected').text();
    var people = $('#people :selected').text();

    console.log('www.lekkeslaap.co.za/akkommodasie-in/'+where+'?q='+where+'&start='+day_1+'+'+month_1+'+'+year_1+'&end='+day_2+'+'+month_2+'+'+year_2+'&pax='+people);
     $("a#atributo").attr("href", "www.lekkeslaap.co.za/akkommodasie-in/"+where+"?q="+where+"&start="+day_1+"+"+month_1+"+"+year_1+'&end='+day_2+'+'+month_2+'+'+year_2+'&pax='+people);

  });
});
```

Comment: You're missing http:// at the beginning of the URL

Comment: Add `http://` (or `htpps://`) at the front of your url.  Without this, the browser assumes it's a *relative* url and appends it to the site page (as you've found).

Comment: Add http:// to the start of the url for attr function.

Comment: Forgot that little detail. Appreciate the support. It works now